# How to use Taylor series to show the approximation holds for small angle $\Delta \phi$?

Tags: calculus

An approximation is used to derive $\Delta r≈r\Delta \phi$. From the Taylor series expansion of sine function about 0. Show that the approximation holds for small angle $\Delta \phi$.

This question is related to centripetal motion. But I haven't learnt Taylor series before so I have no idea how to solve this question.

For me, as I know that sin $x ≈ x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots$

For small angle, $\sin(\phi)$ can be considered as $\phi$.  But how can I show the approximation holds for small angle $\Delta \phi$?

Should I just use $\lim x$ approaches to 0 $\phi ≈ x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots$?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I dunno,  this question is derived from physics teaching material...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

BC=2r sin θ/2
  =2r (θ/2−θ^3/(3!*8)+θ^5/(5!*32)....)

  =2r (θ/2)                                        [cause x is very very small]

  =r*θ

---

if you haven't learnt taylor series than this explanation will be better and simpler:-
When θ becomes very small  we can easily say that BC becomes small.
When ∠BAC becomes very very small we can treat BC as a line segment.This step can be done because arc(BC) is so small that it can now be considered to be a line segment.

NOW we can apply the approximation  Δr≈rΔø as you said and it would make sense

Comment: Nice. With this construction, you can write $\sin\theta/2 = \frac{BD}{AB} =\frac {BD}{\sqrt{BD^2+AD^2}}$. It's not hard to show how this tends to the result for small $\theta$.